# Hardcoding url works in services.php but route name does not work

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am learning Login with GMail. For that, I had to set the gmail api credentials in services.php

I tried two procedures:

**Working part**

```
'google' => [
    'client_id'     => 'ID',
    'client_secret' => 'Secret',
    'redirect'      => 'http://localhost:1234/register',
],
```

**Not Working Part**

```
'google' => [
    'client_id'     => 'ID',
    'client_secret' => 'Secret',
    'redirect'      => route('showGoogleRegistrationForm'),
],
```

Can somebody suggest why it should not work if I write route name instead of hard coding the url?

**Error Details**

```
Route [showGoogleRegistrationForm] not defined.
```

[image]

Comment: It will not work because service.php execute first and then routes file execute so to solve this you may try url()

Comment: May I know, if there is any doc for this statement? Reason I asked this because I mentioned route, url and it's controller details in same class,

Comment: I faced this problem. Not sure for the document but I fixed it by remove route method from service.php.

You are right about details same in class but this is service.php not accepting route method